# check_box_tag and find condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
  <%= check_box_tag('videos_count')%>
```

If this box is checked, the param will say "videos_count"=>"1" .  In the controller I have this:

```
    videos_count = params[:videos_count]
  @cars = Car.paginate( :page => params[:page], :per_page => 10,  
                        :conditions => ["videos_count = ?", videos_count],
```

when the box is checked I see the correct parameter in the server log, but the find returns all of the results instead of results with videos_count = 1.

Comment: why would you want to only return cars with a single video?  that may be what you want, but naming the check_box videos_count is then very misleading.  My guess if you've got the paginate method arguments mixed up.  I don't have the doc handy to check right now.

Answer (score 0):

Check the datatype of  'videos_count' if it's Tiny INT then following may worh. No checked though.

```
:conditions => ["videos_count = ?", true]
```

Comment: videos_count is an integer.  Manually putting in true or 1 does not work.

Comment: I will also add that the videos_count is a counter_cache set up in the video model.

Comment: put a debugger and check the values for params[:videos_count]
, @cars

Comment: If videos_count is an integer why are you using a checkbox?

Comment: I created a has_vid column in the db with boolean datatype.  In the view I made the box with <%= check_box_tag('has_vid', true)%>.  But the find is still not recognizing the boolean condition.

Comment: I can get the boolean condition to work in the find on its own
    :conditions => ["has_vid = true"]


But when I integrate it with everything else it doesn't seem to work.  

 car = params[:car][:category_id]
   min_age = params[:min_age]
   max_age = params[:max_age]
   has_vid = params[:has_vid]

 :conditions => ["category_id = ? AND years >= ? AND years <= ? AND has_vid = ? ", user, min_age, max_age, has_vid] && {:show => true},

Answer (score 0):

What will the output for this?

```
:conditions => ["videos_count = ?", 1])
```

I think there is an issue with your table.